# Solve $z$ from this equation

Tags: complex-numbers

> Find all complex solutions of $$e^{-iz}=\frac{-i+\sqrt 2+1}{-i-\sqrt 2-1}$$
> If a solution is $z=x+iy$ we set $\mathfrak{Re}(z)=x$ and $\mathfrak{Im}(z)=y$.

How do you solve this problem. I multiplied numerator and denominator by the complex conjugate of the denominator $(i-\sqrt 2-1)$. After a lot of simplifications, I get $-0.5\sqrt 2 +0.5\sqrt 2 i$.

$e^{-zi}$ is then equal to $-0.5\sqrt 2+0.5\sqrt 2$. Am I right? Now, how to find $z$?

Comment: Think about Euler.

Comment: is -z not just -0.5sqrt(2)+0.5sqrt(2)

Comment: do your homework

Comment: @RobinBarels, you have got $$e^{-iz}=e^{i\frac{3π}{4}}$$

Comment: yes, but if I take z=a+bi) and put that in, I get e^-ai+b and then b=0 and a= -3pi/4 so z would only have a real part. Because it has to be equal to e^3p/4 i with absoluate value 1 so e^b =1 b=0

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$\frac{-i+\sqrt 2+1}{-i-\sqrt 2-1}\frac{i-\sqrt 2-1}{i-\sqrt 2-1}=\frac{-2-2\sqrt 2+i(2+2\sqrt 2)}{4+2\sqrt2}=-\frac{\sqrt 2}2+i\frac{\sqrt 2}2$$

then use Euler's formula

$$e^{-iz}=e^{y-ix}=e^y\left(\cos x-i\sin x\right)$$

Comment: if you write z= (a+bi) then e^-iz becomes e^b+e^-ai, if that has to be equal to e^3pi/4 i then b is zero, and a is equal to -3pi/4?

Answer (score 0):

Express $e^{a + b i} = e^a (\cos b + i \, \sin b)$, and go from there.

Comment: so e^-zi = cos(-z)+i sin(-z) ?

Comment: To @RobinBarels: $e^{-zi} = e^{-(a+bi)i}=e^{-ai-bi^2}=e^{-ai+b}$

Comment: So e^b * cos(-a) + i sin(-a)

Comment: If i calculate the absolute value of -0.5sqrt(2) +0.5sqrt(2)i I would get 1 so that would mean e^b would be 1, then b is zero,